# Floating div in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is a div,

```
<div id='show' style='display:none;'></div>
```

I edit some contents to through javascript like,

```
 document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('show').title = el.innerHTML;
```

Also this div is shown at a mouse over.
How ever the user scrolls the page the div should appear in the the view at the bottom.How can this be achieved.

***Edit***

Also can u tell me whats wrong with this..

```
var ele=document.getElementById('show'); 
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = el.innerHTML; 
ele.width='200px'; 
ele.height='30px';  
ele.bgcolor='#a9a9a9'; 
ele.color='#fff'; 
ele.position='absolute'; 
ele.display='block'; 

$(window).mouseover(function(event) { 
    $("#show").css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX}); 
    $('#show').height(); 
});
```

The div doesnt show up.This is inside a function and is invoked on mouse over

Comment: Enclose the event handler inside `$(function(){});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can avoid IE6 then you can use the `position: fixed` property.

See [**position**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534345(VS.85).aspx) property

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">
    I am at the bottom of the page
</div>
```

***Edit- div attached to the mouse pointer***

```
<style type="text/css">
#div1 { width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: #a9a9a9; color: #fff; position: absolute; }
</style>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(window).mousemove(function(event){
        $("#div1").css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX});  
    });
});
</script>
<div id="div1">move me</div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/owobo3)**

Comment: And if you can't, you'll probably need to dig your way trough this :) http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

Comment: Also can u tell me whats wrong with this..
var ele=document.getElementById('show');
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
        ele.width='200px';
        ele.height='30px';
        ele.bgcolor='#a9a9a9';
        ele.color='#fff';
        ele.position='absolute';
        ele.display='block';
        $(window).mouseover(function(event) {
         $("#show").css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX});
        $('#show').height();
        
        });

The div doesnt show up.This is inside a function and is invoked on mouse over.........